# Change class depending on time left

Tags: javascript

How do I go about changing classes depending on X time left till the 0 hour (currently being 2pm)

For example, I want the to change the class when the time is within 5 hours till 2pm. ( `start.setHours(14, 0, 0); // 2pm`)

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(14, 0, 0); // 2pm

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
      hh + "hrs&nbsp;" + mm + "mins&nbsp;" + ss + "secs&nbsp;";
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "within 5 hours" - do you mean between 9am and 7pm? (5 hours before/ 5 hours after) Please clarify. Can you add some html also and the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  var counts = [10,5,2,1]
  var colors = ["orange","pink","yellow","red"]
  var time = document.getElementById('time');
  start.setHours(14, 0, 0); // 2pm

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function getClass(hh) { 
    var nearest = counts.filter(v => v <= hh)[0]; // get nearest number
    return colors[counts.indexOf(nearest)] || "";
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    time.className = getClass(hh);
    time.innerHTML =
      hh + "hrs&nbsp;" + mm + "mins&nbsp;" + ss + "secs&nbsp;";
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```css
.orange { background-color: orange }
.pink   { background-color: pink }
.yellow { background-color: yellow }
.red    { background-color: red }
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks so much. Just to double check The counts of 10, 5, 3, 1 - they're hours difference between the setHours?

Comment: Just examples. 10 is until 10 hours before deadline, 5 until 5 hours etc. Remove what your do not need